# Show that $W_p[0,1]\subset L^q[0,1]$ for $0<q<p$ where $W_p[0,1]$ is the set of functions s.t. $ |\{x\in[0,1]\colon|f(x)|>a\}|\le\frac{C}{a^p}$

Tags: real-analysis

> For $0<p<\infty$, let $W_p[0,1]$ be the collection of measurable $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that there is a constant $C=C_f>0$ for which
>   $$ |\{x\in[0,1]\colon|f(x)|>a\}|\le\frac{C}{a^p} $$
>   for all $a>0$. Show that $W_p[0,1]\subset L^q[0,1]$ for $0<q<p$.

---

My attempt:

For $f\in W_p[0,1]$ we are supposed to show that
$$ \int_0^1|f|^q<\infty .$$
Write $|f|^q$ into
$$ |f|^q=|f|^q \chi\{|f|^q>a^q\}+|f|^q\chi\{|f|^q\le a^q\}. $$
I was about to apply the Holder's inequality, but without knowing the integrability of some powers of $|f|$, it is hard to proceed. So I think we should try something different. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard formula based on Fubini's Theorem is $\int |f|^{q} d\mu =\int_0^{\infty} \mu \{x:|f(x)|^{q} >t\} dt$. Split the integral into integrals from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$. For the second integral use the fact that $\mu \{x:|f(x)|^{q} >t\} \leq \frac C {t^{p/q}}$. Since $q<p$ the integral of $t^{-p/q}$ is finite.